# Code First - Setting Cascade Rule to "Set Null" in one to many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I was wondering how set up a one-to-many relationship which has Cascade rule **"Set Null"**. Here the two entities that I am using. The StandradRelay has one-to-many relationship with RelayConfig.

```
public class StandardRelay {
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<RelayConfig> RelayConfigs { get; set; }
}

public class RelayConfig  {
    ...
    public virtual StandardRelay StandardRelay { get; set; }
}
```

By default the above code results in Cascade rule of **"No Action"**. So I tried using DbModelBuilder with the following fluent API.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<StandardRelay>()
            .HasMany<RelayConfig>(s => s.RelayConfigs)
            .WithOptional(r => r.StandardRelay)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

This again results in Cascade rule of **"No Action"**. Then I tried the following

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<StandardRelay>()
                    .HasMany<RelayConfig>(s => s.RelayConfigs)
                    .WithOptional(r => r.StandardRelay)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

This results in cascade rule of **"Delete"**.

So in short I don't see any option to set a Cascade Rule of "Set Null". How do we configure the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible.

You'll have to handle it manually.